# Delay in Promises chain resolution

Tags: javascript, promise

I try to execute promises sequentially but something goes wrong in timing...

When I execute the following code, I got instantly the five responses "I'm XXX and I get YY" and after 2 seconds, I got the "Success" message.

That I want is  first to get messages "I'm XXX and I get YY" spaced by 2 seconds then the success one.

Any idea ?

```
"use strict";
Promise.resolve()
  .then(doStuff)
  .then(function () {
    console.log("Success");
})

function doStuff() {
  let item = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  // Construction du tableau de promises
  let array = item.map(i => {
    let pro =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Item " + i);
        }, 2000 );
      });
    pro.custom = i;
    return pro;
  });

  let pro = array.reduce((p, item) => {
      return p.then((val) => {
        console.log("I'm " + item.custom + " and I get " + val);
        return Date.now();
      });
  }, Promise.resolve());

  return pro;
}
```

(and sorry for my poor english).

Comment: Very hard to read inconsistently indented code with multiple levels in it.

Comment: OK, I just discover StackOverflow online editor. I try to do better indentation in the future (I promise)...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, all the delays are started at the same time, which is why they all finish in a flurry at once, and why there's a single 2 second delay betwewn doStuff and `Success` message

If you change doStuff as follows, the output should be identical but with 2 second delay between items in the array

```
function doStuff() {
  let item = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  let delay = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
  return item.reduce((p, val, i) => 
    p
    .then(() => delay(2000))
    .then(() => {
        console.log("I'm " + i + " and I get " + val);
        return Date.now();
    }), Promise.resolve());
}
```